# (call/cc): What exactly is continuation?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, continuations

This question have been asked several times on SO, but none of them solve my question. **What is continuation?**

Consider the following code:

```
( (lambda (pair)
     (begin (print (car pair))
            ((cdr pair) (cons (+ 1 (car pair)) 
                              (cdr pair)))))

  (call/cc (lambda (k) 
             (cons 0 k))))
```

This program loops indefinitely printing the sequence of integers starting
from 0.

What I understand is:

Step 1: `(call/cc (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)))` is evaluated, return pair `(0 . #continuation)` **(What is `#continuation` in here)**

Step 2: Apply the pair from step 1 to a lambda function. The lambda function first print out the `car`, which is 0.

**Now, I am totally lost**. The program is evaluating `(#continuation (1 . #continuation))`, which does not really make sense to me. Is `#continuation` a procedure now?

What makes the program keep applying `(call/cc (lambda (k) (cons 0 k)))` to the lambda function? So that it can keep calling itself

Answer (score 3):

I think I have figured it out.

**Continuation is the current state of the program**

Given this, first we need to ask: what is the continuation, or the current state of this program?

It is a lambda function waiting for a pair.

`#continuation = ( lambda-function <placeholder>)`

`<placeholder>` would be whatever we will pass to that lambda function, but we have not done that yet.

Now our program start to run, it evaluates the lambda function, then it evaluate the pair return by call/cc, which is `(0 . #continuation)`.

`(print (car pair))` => Next the lambda function prints out 0

`((cdr pair) (cons (+ 1 (car pair)) (cdr pair)))))` => Here, `(cdr pair)` is our `continuation`, which is `(lambda-function <placeholder>)`, then our program pass a new pair into it. Then the program starts its infinite loop

Comment: you got it. evaluating `( f x )` in Scheme means evaluating `f` to find its value, and the same for `x` (in some unspecified order), and then calling the value of `f` with the value of `x`, as a function application. So the context for `x` is "call `f` with the supplied value", which is the continuation at that point.  `k` captures it; `cons` passes it as part of a `cons` pair.

Comment: and BTW this is unrelated to CPS.